# How can I plot the direction field for a differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'd like to plot the graph of the direction field for a differential equation, to get a feel for it.  I'm a novice, right now, when it comes to plotting in Mathematica, so I'm hoping that someone can provide a fairly easy to understand and thorough explanation.  My hope is that I will become fairly proficient at understanding plotting in Mathematica, as well as differential equations.  I'm a little more familiar with differential equations, but very far from what I'd consider to be an expert.

I do have an equation in mind, taken from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134482/solving-a-differential-equation-involving-y-and-its-exponential) from Math.SE:

$$y'=\dfrac{y+e^x}{x+e^y}$$

I ran `DSolve` on it, and after a minute it was unable to evaluate the function.  So perhaps this could make for an interesting exploration for others as well.  I'm wondering what experience in Mathematica has taught others about what can be done in Mathematica - I'm hoping someone can offer some useful tips and demonstrations.

I'm really interested in learning about what can be done with differential equations, so I think that other equations will suffice if they serve as a better example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For a first sketch of the direction field you might use `StreamPlot`:

```
f[x_, y_] = (y + E^x)/(x + E^y)

StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 1, 6}, {y, -20, 5}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 22):

No need to solve the differential equation to generate a direction field. According to the [Wikipedia lemma on slope fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field) you can plot the vector `{1, (y + Exp[x])/(x + Exp[y])}`:

```
VectorPlot[{1, (y + Exp[x])/(x + Exp[y])}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or perhaps you could use a stream plot:

```
StreamPlot[{1, (y + Exp[x])/(x + Exp[y])}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 18):

If you wish to explore the solutions to an equation I'd suggest the `EquationTrekker` package. Have a look at the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/EquationTrekker/tutorial/EquationTrekker.html).

```
Needs["EquationTrekker`"]
EquationTrekker[y'[x] == (y[x] + Exp[x])/(x + Exp[y[x]]), y, {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: trekker]

Answer (score 14):

Here is something you can do quickly and gives a nice understanding of the behavior for positive and negative initial conditions:

```
s[r_?NumericQ] := 
               NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == (y[x] + E^x)/(x + E^y[x]), y[0] == r}, y, {x, 0, 5}]

Plot[Evaluate[
  y[x] /. s[#] & /@ Union[Range[-2, 0, .1], Range[-.10, 10, 1]]], {x, 0, 15}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 13):

In the most popular contemporary undergraduate calculus textbooks, including those by Larson and Edwards, Stewart, Rogawski and Adams, and others, a *slope field* (also called a *direction field*) is a plot of short line segments at grid points all having the same length and without an arrowhead indicating direction. A slope field indicates only the slope of the solution curve at each grid point by the slope of the line segment only. Only Wesley Wolfe's answer approaches this method of plotting slope fields as of this writing. I adjust a couple of options to `VectorPlot[]` in his answer below.

We assume that the D.E. can be written in the form $y'=F(x,y)$, where $F(x, y)$ is a function only of two variables $x$ and $y$. Then we can plot the slope field in *Mathematica* as follows:

```
F[x_, y_] := (E^x + y)/(E^y + x)

VectorPlot[
  {1, F[x, y]}/Sqrt[1 + F[x, y]^2],
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  VectorScale -> 0.02, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine,
  VectorStyle -> "Segment"
]
```

[image]

There are some textbooks that prefer to put arrows on the line segments. To emulate this effect, change `VectorStyle` from `"Segment"` to `"Arrow"`. However, this style is misleading and should be avoided, as the arrows generally *do not* point in the direction of the solution curves as they are traced out. To take an example from my bookshelf, Boyce and DiPrima's *Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems*, 7th edition., p. 40-41: We consider $y'=\frac{x^2}{1-y^2}$ which has general solution $-x^3+3y-y^3=c$. They give the slope field—with arrowheads—in figure 2.2.1, but you can plot it with *Mathematica* as I have along with a few solution curves below:

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2/(1 - y^2);

Show[ VectorPlot[
  {1, F[x, y]}/Sqrt[1 + F[x, y]^2],
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, VectorScale -> 0.03, VectorPoints -> Fine, 
  VectorStyle -> "Arrow"], 
 Table[ContourPlot[-x^3 + 3 y - y^3 == c, {x, -4,  4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red], {c, {-4, -1, 1,  4}}]]
```

[image]

At some point somebody must have objected to this abomination, because the arrowheads are gone from all slope fields in the 9th edition!

Comment: As a supplement, use `{1, F[x, y]}*n/Sqrt[F[x, y]^2 + n^2]` if your plot has different x and y ranges. Here `n` is the range ratio of y vs. x.

Answer (score 8):

I approached this slightly differently, in an attempt to mimic what's written in a textbook of mine for direction fields. I set the plot as a system of unit vectors, with x and y from this derivation:

$$\mathit{x}^2+\mathit{y}^2=1\wedge \mathit{m}=\frac{y}{\mathit{x}}\Rightarrow
 \\
 \\ \mathit{x}=\frac{\mathit{y}}{\mathit{m}}\Rightarrow
 \\ \frac{\mathit{y}^2}{\mathit{m}^2}+\mathit{y}^2=1\Rightarrow
 \\ \mathit{y}=\frac{\mathit{m}}{\sqrt{\mathit{m}^2+1}}
$$

$$
 \\ \mathit{y}=\mathit{m} \mathit{x}\Rightarrow
 \\ \mathit{m}^2 \mathit{x}^2+\mathit{x}^2=1\Rightarrow
 \\ \mathit{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathit{m}^2+1}}
$$
So I put this into *Mathematica*

```
func =
  Function[{m},
    VectorPlot[
      {1/Sqrt[1 + m[x, y]^2], m[x, y]/Sqrt[1 + m[x, y]^2]}, 
      {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
      VectorPoints -> Fine]];
```

When given the original equation and one of the ones from my textbook it displays:

```
Column[func /@ {Function[{x, y}, (E^x + y)/(E^y + x)], Function[{x, y}, y (y - 3)]}]
```

[image: Graph of m=(y+e^x)/(x+e^y)] [image: Graph of m=(y*(y-3))]

Which gets very close to what I see my textbook. The range and options can be adjusted as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica 12, `VectorPlot` is much more user-friendly. You don't need to mess with `VectorScale` parameters. The default behavior of `VectorPlot` is to draw direction-field-style vectors.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot.html

Here is how I define my direction field plot function:

```
DirectionFieldPlot[F_, (* expression for y' *)
  xr_, (* x range *)
  yr_, (* y range *)
  init_, (* initial conditions (list of points) *)
  colors_List : {}, (* colors corresponding to initial points *)
  OptionsPattern[{LineWidth -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    VectorPoints -> 30}] (* Linewith is thickness of the curves. 
  The other two are parameters of VectorPlot *)
  ] :=
 Module[{cv},
  cv = If[TrueQ[colors == {}], 
    Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][i], {i, 
      Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[init] + 1)][[2 ;; -2]]}], colors];
  Show[VectorPlot[{1, F}, xr, yr, 
    VectorPoints -> OptionValue[VectorPoints], 
    VectorStyle -> "Segment", Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    VectorColorFunction -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {Take[xr, -2], Take[yr, -2]}, 
    AspectRatio -> OptionValue[AspectRatio]],
   StreamPlot[{1, F}, xr, yr, 
    PlotRange -> {Take[xr, -2], Take[yr, -2]}, 
    StreamPoints -> {Table[{init[[i]], {cv[[i]], 
         OptionValue[LineWidth]}}, {i, Length[init]}], Automatic, 
      10^50}, StreamScale -> None]]
  ]
```

To avoid `DSolve` and `NDSolve`, I use `StreamPlot` to plot the curves. You don't need to solve a differential equation for visualization.

Here are some examples:

`DirectionFieldPlot[(y + E^x)/(x + E^y), {x, 0, 5}, {y, -2.5, 6},  Join[{{0, -1.5}, {0, -1.3}}, Table[{0, i}, {i, -1, 5, 1}]]]`

[image]

`DirectionFieldPlot[15 - 3 y, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 6},  Table[{0, i}, {i, 0, 6, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1/2]`

[image]

`DirectionFieldPlot[x^2/y^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},  Table[{0, i}, {i, -2.5, 2.5, 0.5}], VectorPoints -> 40]`

[image]