# Plotting the direction field of a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have to sketch the direction field for the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-0.02 y +0.00002 xy}{0.08 x-0.001xy}$$

This is the code I used, which gives an incorrect plot:

```
StreamPlot[Normalize[{1, (y (-0.016 + 0.00008 x))/(x (0.12 - 0.006 y))}], 
    {x, -200, 200}, {y, -200, 200}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

The following picture shows what I need to get:

[image]

Comment: I think this is duplicate  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/how-can-i-plot-the-direction-field-for-a-differential-equation "How can I plot the direction field for a differential equation?"

Comment: @Nasser The user has already tried `StreamPlot` as shown there and says the result is incorrect, so I don't think it is a duplicate outright.  Thanks for looking for duplicates however!

Comment: data = Table[{1, dyx}, {x, 1, 3000, 10}, {y, 1, 150}]; ListStreamPlot[data] comes close. I'm not saying it's an answer, just 'closer'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is getting close to what you want:

```
f[x_, y_] := (-0.02 y + 0.00002 x y)/(0.08 x - 0.001 x y)

VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 3100}, {y, 0, 150}, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[{}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `VectorPlot` is addressed in the post that Nasser linked to... besides, OP's main fault is plotting a different equation than the one that they actually want!

Comment: @rm-rf Oh, well I guess we can delete this in a little while then.

Comment: `VectorPlot[{5 , f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 3100}, {y, 0.1, 150}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3100}, {0, 150}}, VectorScale -> .03]` is a little more aligned with the OP's plot

Comment: By the way, how to get arrows with the equal lengths? Because of the large aspect ratio (3100/150), they  always have different lengths...

Comment: @ybeltukov I'll admit I tried for a few minutes to get that (I was using `VectorScale`) but I failed.  I intend to return to it later.  Let me know if you figure it out before I do!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you do not mind, I put it as a separate answer.

Comment: @ybeltukov Of course, I do not mind.  What you did was definitely the harder part of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think the following is a bit closer

```
f[x_, y_] := (-0.02 y + 0.00002 x y)/(0.08 x - 0.001 x y)
{X1, X2} = {0, 3100};
{Y1, Y2} = {0, 150};
AR = 0.5;
length = 0.04;
VectorPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, X1, X2}, {y, Y1, Y2}, AspectRatio -> AR, 
 PlotRange -> {{X1, X2}, {Y1, Y2}}, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[{}], 
 VectorScale -> {length, Automatic, If[#5 > 0, #5/Sqrt[#3^2 + (AR(X1-X2)#4/(Y1-Y2))^2],0] &}]
```

[image]

This solution gives the equal lengths of the arrows with taking into account the aspect ratio.

Comment: The lines above/below (250, 80) look shorter to me.  I think you want `#5/Sqrt[..]` inside the `If` in `VectorScale`.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103179/how-to-adjust-vector-scaling-with-a-specific-aspect-ratio/103180#103180

Comment: @MichaelE2 You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume that what you really want is a `StreamPlot` and not a vector plot, because that's in your code.

The equation you're plotting in the question isn't the one in the first equation. But even if we correct this, the `StreamPlot` looks bad because it cuts off the automatically generated streamlines before they are long enough to outline the shape of the slope field.

To remedy this, you can try specifying a minimum length for the streamlines, and also choose them to go through the interesting points in the plot. I've taken your (corrected) `StreamPlot` and added the necessary `StreamPoints` option:

```
StreamPlot[
 Normalize[{1, (-0.02 y + 0.00002 x y)/(0.08 x - 
      0.001 x y)}], {x, 0, 3000}, {y, 0, 150}, Axes -> True, 
 StreamPoints -> {Table[{1040, i}, {i, 13, 150, 5}], Automatic, 3000},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: swirl]