# Direction Field for an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have found links for plot the direction field of a differential equation. For example:

[How can I plot the direction field for a differential equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/how-can-i-plot-the-direction-field-for-a-differential-equation)

And:

[Plotting the direction field of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/plotting-the-direction-field-of-a-differential-equation)

But when I am teaching differential equations in the spring 2015, these are not the forms I would prefer. I am struggling mightily with the VectorScale options unitlen, aratio, sfun, so much so that I fear my students would not be able to handle these.

The equation I am dealing with is:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-t}-2y$$

If I do the following:

```
VectorPlot[{1, Exp[-t] - 2 y}, {t, -2, 3}, {y, -1, 2}, Axes -> True]
```

I get the following image:

[image]

Now, the difficulty here is that some of the arrows overlap, some are too small to interpret. I've spent about 4 hours this morning playing with the VectorScale command, trying to understand unitlen, a ratio, and sfun, but minimal success. So far, here is the best image I have come up with. I normalized all the vectors so they had length one, then I set the VectorScale to 0.03.

VectorPlot[Normalize[{1, Exp[-t] - 2*y}], {t, -2, 3}, {y, -1, 2}, 
 VectorScale -> .03,
 Axes -> True
 ]

Here is the resulting image:

[image]

This is the one I like the best so far, but I am just a beginner. If folks on this site have better suggestions so that I can easily help students who have never used Mathematica before, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Mark McClure has done some nice things.  E.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43155/streamplot-for-bifurcation-diagram/43174#43174

Comment: Related: [43478](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/how-to-visualize-slope-fields-of-differential-equations-without-vectors)

Comment: @Pickett I can't imagine a better answer than Mark's answer to [43478](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/how-to-visualize-slope-fields-of-differential-equations-without-vectors).  I suppose one could replace the 0.03 by 0.5 divided by the number of `VectorPoints` (15), or deal with the slightly off lengths due to the `AspectRatio`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree with you so much that I initially (before I commented) voted to close this as a duplicate, but my insecurity got the better of me and I retracted my vote so now I've lost my voting rights :)

Comment: @Pickett No big deal.  Good find, although I realize you may have had an advantage. :)