# StreamPlot a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How do I `StreamPlot` the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin (y)$ in *Mathematica*. I get blank axes each time. I don't quite understand the documentation regarding the first set of parameters.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8848/4999

Comment: Thanks but sin [y] does not produce any results. Am I typing the function in properly? Also, why is the first parameter always "1"?

Comment: Mathematica is case sensitive.  Use `Sin[y]`.

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with basic language fundamentals. For instance, all built-in functions start with a capital, including standard mathematics functions.  Here's one starting place: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GettingStartedOverview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
StreamPlot[{1, Sin[y]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> False, 
            Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This gives

[image]